# How fast FormControl's setValue actually works?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, angular-material, angular-forms

For a example I have a huge array of strings and the amount of strings continues to increase over time (I'm getting updated array via websocket every second).
All I need is to show all of the strings in component. Well, the easiest solution is ngFor and wrap each string in div but I don't like the idea of a few hundreds div's in component.
So I decided to try to use just one textarea like this (briefly):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput [formControl]='myArrayofStrings'></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in component just update this value every time when I get new array:

```
this.myArrayofStrings.setValue(newArray);
```

So, my **question is** - how reliable, smart and fast this solution would be?

Maybe there are any other more clever solutions for this, you know, trivial task.
(*btw my stack is Angular 7, Angular Material*)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "reliable, smart and fast"? Don't use Angular. `console.time('testOne'); doStuff(); console.timeEnd('testOne');`.

Comment: @PHPglue yeah, nice answer : ) That's may be a solution : ))

Comment: I'd question why a user needs to see a list of hundreds of items rendered so visually inaccessible and updated so frequently. Seems like that'd be of no use to them.

Comment: Well, it’s some kind of logs showing current working device

Comment: And a user is supposed to "work" with that in any meaningful way when the values are just dumped into a textarea?

Comment: Yeah. Well, I understand your puzzle, I had the same when I first time ‘ve seen it :) But the guys just wanna be sure that everything working is okay, they do not read out every line

Comment: So then maybe display the number of items instead of the entire list? Or the number and the first few items or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no good way of updating a big data object constantly for single line updates. In Angular, if an object referenced in the template gets changed, it will be **fully re-rendered**, and in your case, it will generate obsolete rendering as your earlier data logs won't change ... so you must separate the log you get from the request, and the data you show to the user to avoid UI crash on big data.

Some ideas:

1. **Create a table:** Create a datasource for a standard angular material
   table, from the log you get from the socket, but only use the data upon table datasource get: I mean every time, the table requests its data, you check the
   ever-growing object of yours, and return accordingly. For instance,
   you can use pagination, or set a "refresh" button and only re-render
   on user demand. (good base to start for this would be [table examples /Table retrieving data through HTTP](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)
2. **Extract to smaller chunks:**
   Create an "array of buckets", and only push to the "buckets". For instance: every bucket can hold 100 line of log, and you only update the current bucket as long as it is filling up. That way only the last 1-99 lines are get re-rendered, the other items won't.
3. **Create data bundles**
   Create objects, that are lines and only update them, if the new data exceeds a given length. For instance, you only update the view after 50 new lines arrive, or in every x. seconds - that way you separate the rendering and the websocket event, allowing time for the UI to render.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me some info for contemplation... Right now in component I just 'slow down' the rendering using auditTime(1000)... A bit like your third advice...